# ccavenue - How to integrate Internet banking

Tags: php, ccavenue

I am working on ccavenue payment integration where I need to setup internet banking option for customers but I got only credit card script through their site.

Is there any way to integrate internet banking using ccavenue?

Comment: ask your bank to give you the api

Answer (score 0):

See CCAvenue's payment option:

http://www.ccavenue.com/widest_range_of_payment_options.jsp

If what you want is there you can do it, if not then not.

Comment: I can see netbanking option here - https://login.ccavenue.com/web/registration.do?command=navigateSchemeForm